# Looking for gridded wind field data for Sicily and surrounding region

Tags: geospatial, weather, europe

I'm trying to locate gridded wind field (wind direction and speed) data for Sicily and surrounding region, including surrounding sea and southern part of Italy? It's for a student practical here at Portsmouth University.

Any pointers would be very welcome.

Comment: I would start with a search of the [INSPIRE GeoPortal](http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/discovery/)